Combining arrays with bicep
In bicep, is there any good way to treat an array as a set, specifically I'd like to have an array setup in my main bicep file, say:
concat(paramArray, [
  {
    name: 'Foo'
    value: 'FooValue'
  }
])

I would like to be able to overwrite the Foo value from the param file:
param paramArray = [
  {
    name: 'Foo'
    value: 'BazValue'
  }
]

I would like to end up with the BazValue.

Do you want to get only BazValue !

Yes, that's correct.

Have you tried merging these two arrays and overwrite values based on the key? @Max

Please give me an example how that would look. Or do you mean further logic to do it manually in a foreach?

Let me try working out the approach. @Max

Have you checked this example from MSDoc. @Max

Yes, that will add new elements, no unique check, so there will be both FooValue and BazValue.

Can you check the below approach if this works. @Max

Have you checked it. @Max

To overwrite the Foo value from the param file end up with the BazValue in the resultant array, you can use union and filter operators available in Bicep which is detailed below.
Filter lambda:

Filters an array with a custom filtering function.

Union operator:

Returns a single array or object with all elements from the parameters. For arrays, duplicate values are included once.

param defaultarray array = [
  {
    name: 'Foo'
    value: 'value'
  }
]
param paramArray array = [
  {
  name:  'Foo'
  value: 'BazValue'
  }
 ]
var combinedArray = [for item in defaultarray: union(item, {
    value: last(filter(paramArray, i => i.name == item.name)).value
  })]
output resultArray array = combinedArray

Output:


References:
Union, Filter
